# How can I get the width of an iOS device in pixels?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I get the width of an iOS device in pixels? I don't want to hardcode 320×480 or anything like that... I want to get the width dynamically.

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get the screen size in pixels (not points) would be:

```
CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].currentMode.size;
```

This is easier than using other approaches involving getting the size in points, getting the scale, and doing some math on the two.